# PasswordSignInAsync method in AspNetIdentity throw invalid format exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, asp.net-identity

I have a strange error using Asp Net Identity.
According to this site : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity I have changed AspNetUsers table primary key type from VARCHAR2(128) to Int, because I need after an user registration to insert hit to another table with an Int primary key.

I have some problems with authentication after that : passwordsigninasync function throw exception for invalid format whereas I have checked each parameter and try to keep values as "gaetan@sfr.fr" for email, "Justeacote1!" as password and false false.

Here is the error:
System.FormatException: Le format de la chaîne d'entrée est incorrect.

```
[FormatException: Le format de la chaîne d'entrée est incorrect.]
   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +12732673
   System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +120
   System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider) +46
   System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider) +483
   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.ChangeType(Object sourceValue, Type targetType) +764
   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i) +3800
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetUntypedValueDefault(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal) +10
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal) +149
   lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) +269
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper) +181
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.<MoveNextAsync>d__4.MoveNext() +366
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<FirstMoveNextAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +499
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.<ForEachAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +327
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.<EnsureRolesLoaded>d__64.MoveNext() +1025
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__67.MoveNext() +1156
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +59
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<PasswordSignInAsync>d__25.MoveNext() +297
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
   JC_PROJECT.Controllers.<Login>d__13.MoveNext() +471
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__11_0() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__3() +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9873701
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159
```

Here is my login function :

```
 [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            // Ceci ne comptabilise pas les échecs de connexion pour le verrouillage du compte
            // Pour que les échecs de mot de passe déclenchent le verrouillage du compte, utilisez shouldLockout: true

           // var user = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email);
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Tentative de connexion non valide.");
                    return View(model);
            }
        }
```

Here my LoginViewModel:

```
public class LoginViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Adresse mail")]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }



        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Mot de passe")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Mémoriser le mot de passe ?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }
```

And my OnModelCreating method:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("AUTH_DEV"); //uppercase  
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserLogin>()
            .HasKey(l => new { l.LoginProvider, l.ProviderKey, l.UserId })
            .ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserRole>()
            .HasKey(r => new { r.UserId, r.RoleId })
            .ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUsers").Property(p => p.UserName).HasColumnName("UserName");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUsers").Property(p => p.AccessFailedCount).HasColumnName("AccessFailedCount");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUsers").Property(p => p.LockoutEnabled).HasColumnName("LockoutEnabled");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUsers").Property(p => p.LockoutEndDateUtc).HasColumnName("LockoutEndDateUtc");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUsers").Property(p => p.TwoFactorEnabled).HasColumnName("TwoFactorEnabled");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUsers").Property(p => p.PhoneNumberConfirmed).HasColumnName("PhoneNumberConfirmed");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUsers").Property(p => p.PhoneNumber).HasColumnName("PhoneNumber");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUsers").Property(p => p.SecurityStamp).HasColumnName("SecurityStamp");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUsers").Property(p => p.PasswordHash).HasColumnName("PasswordHash");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUsers").Property(p => p.EmailConfirmed).HasColumnName("EmailConfirmed");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUsers").Property(p => p.Email).HasColumnName("Email");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUsers").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserRole>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUserRoles").Property(p => p.RoleId).HasColumnName("RoleId");
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserRole>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUserRoles").Property(p => p.UserId).HasColumnName("UserId");
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserLogin>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUserLogins").Property(p => p.UserId).HasColumnName("UserId");
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserLogin>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUserLogins").Property(p => p.ProviderKey).HasColumnName("ProviderKey");
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserLogin>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUserLogins").Property(p => p.LoginProvider).HasColumnName("LoginProvider");
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserClaim>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUserClaims").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserClaim>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUserClaims").Property(p => p.UserId).HasColumnName("UserId");
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserClaim>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUserClaims").Property(p => p.ClaimType).HasColumnName("ClaimType");
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserClaim>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUserClaims").Property(p => p.ClaimValue).HasColumnName("ClaimValue");
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomRole>()
            .ToTable("AspNetRoles").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomRole>()
            .ToTable("AspNetRoles").Property(p => p.Name).HasColumnName("Name");

            //modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");
            //modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserRole>().ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");
            //modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserLogin>().ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");
            //modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserClaim>().ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");
            //modelBuilder.Entity<CustomRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles");
        }

}
```

I am using an Oracle 12C Database. Could anybody help me please? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

change your `OnModelCreating` method like bellow:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("C##AUTH_DEV");
        modelBuilder
            .Properties()
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string) &&
                        !p.Name.Contains("Id") &&
                        !p.Name.Contains("Provider"))
            .Configure(p => p.HasMaxLength(256));

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles").Property(c => c.Name).HasMaxLength(128).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers").Property(c => c.UserName).HasMaxLength(128).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers").Property(c => c.Email).HasMaxLength(128).IsRequired();

        //UPDATE
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>()
            .HasKey(r => new { r.UserId, r.RoleId })
            .ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>()
            .HasKey(l => new { l.LoginProvider, l.ProviderKey, l.UserId })
            .ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");
        //END

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");
    }
```

you can find the full sample project in [github](https://github.com/ashiquzzaman/Mvc5WithOracleDB). Hopefully it's helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have another problem after changing OnModelCreating : 
JC_PROJECT.Models.IdentityUserRole: : Aucune clé n'est définie pour l'EntityType 'IdentityUserRole'. Définissez la clé pour cet EntityType. JC_PROJECT.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : Aucune clé n'est définie pour l'EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin'. Définissez la clé pour cet EntityType. 
I Think I have to map CustomUserRoles, CustomUserLogin, CustomeUserClaims.. instead of default Identity classes because I have changed the primary key type to int in AspNetUsers

Comment: @pyfpyfes I update my answer. please see the update block.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.
I have found the solution :

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

```
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("AUTH_DEV");
        modelBuilder
            .Properties()
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string) &&
                        !p.Name.Contains("Id") &&
                        !p.Name.Contains("Provider"))
            .Configure(p => p.HasMaxLength(256));

        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles").Property(c => c.Name).HasMaxLength(128).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers").Property(c => c.UserName).HasMaxLength(128).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers").Property(c => c.Email).HasMaxLength(128).IsRequired();


        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomRole>()
            .HasKey(r => new { r.Id })
            .ToTable("AspNetRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserClaim>()
            .HasKey(r => new { r.Id })
            .ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserRole>()
        .HasKey(r => new { r.UserId, r.RoleId })
        .ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserLogin>()
            .HasKey(l => new { l.LoginProvider, l.ProviderKey })
            .ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");


        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserRole>().ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");

        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserLogin>().ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserClaim>().ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");
    }
}
```

The problem was in my Oracle Database Tables : after changing primary key of AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles etc., some fields in tables have not been changed from VARCHAR to INT.
I Have use Entity Migration to recreate the tables, and all works fine!

Thank you :)